# Iterate through dataframe and select null values

Tags: python, dataframe, null

I am trying to iterate through a dataframe that has null values for the column = [myCol]. I am able to iterate through the dataframe fine, however when I specify I only want to see null values I get an error.

End goal is that I want to force a value into the fields that are Null which is why I am iterating to identify which are first.

```
for index,row in df.iterrows():
    if(row['myCol'].isnull()):
        print('true')

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'isnull'
```

I tried specifying the column = 'None' since that is the value I see when I print the iteration of the dataframe. Still no luck:

```
for index,row in df.iterrows():
    if(row['myCol']=='None'):
        print('true')

No returned rows
```

Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: did you mean `if(row['myCol'] is None):`? otherwise this will compare to the string `'None'` and not to the (singleton) object `None`.
`

Comment: Your end goal is not clear. Maybe you can provide input table and expected output table. Not sure what you are trying to replace the null value with, is it a vector data or or other df col or other col in the same df?  in R, if you are trying to replace the null values with value from same df. Simple would be to `df$myCol <- ifelse(df$myCol == "", df$FillInColumn, df$myCol)`

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use `pd.isnull()` to check if a value is null or not:

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if(pd.isnull(row['myCol'])):
        print('true')
```

But seems like you need `df.fillna(myValue)` where `myValue` is the value you want to force into fields that are NULL. And also to check the `NULL` fields in a data frame you can invoke `df.myCol.isnull()` instead of looping through rows and check individually.

---

If the columns are of string type, you might also want check if it is empty string:

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if(row['myCol'] == ""):
        print('true')
```